# Can we control the flow of for loop in swift (dispatch group)

Tags: react-native

I want to control the For loop in react native. So that i can perform custom method with each iteration.Or any other way to do this.(I want to perform custom function within the for loop. So my function will wait for the first iteration need to be complete and then second will execute and so on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your custom function you are calling is asyncronous, then you should prodbably use the promise to wait for the result. I have added exaple for your reference.

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
    asyncCall()
}


function asyncCall() {
  var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve('foo');
  }, 5000);
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  // expected output: "foo"
});
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response but this delay execution at a same time print numbers at a same time (0,1,2,3,4) with 5 sec of delay. can it return 0 then 1 then 2 and so on..

Answer (score 2):

You should try **generator** functions.

[More details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)